# gazebo fuerte crashes after calling gazebo/delete_model service

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I was following the simulator_gazebo tutorial on ROS wiki when I encountered this problem. First of all I spawned a model using " rosrun gazebo spawn_model -param coffee_cup_description -gazebo -model coffee_cup -x 0 -z 2 " and then I deleted it using " rosservice call gazebo/delete_model '{model_name: coffee_cup}' ". After I called the delete_model command,gazebo crashed unexpectedly and gave the following:

[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 3162, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/chengxiang/.ros/log/fba33798-f058-11e1-8139-0017c4794a79/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/chengxiang/.ros/log/fba33798-f058-11e1-8139-0017c4794a79/gazebo_gui-3*.log

Other than this instance, gazebo also crashes unexpectedly sometimes when I was doing other stuffs like spawning models. Did any one of you encounter this issues before? Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42398/gazebo-fuerte-crashes-after-calling-gazebo/delete_model-service/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-08-27**:
On a side note, my gazebo sometimes launches with a blackout screen, could this be related?

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-08-27**:
In addition, I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please file a bug report on [gazebo trac](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new), and include all details needed to reproduce the error, as well as any debugging information if available.  Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-08-29**:
Hi Hsu. Actually the problem seem to disappear for now, after i installed the driver for my graphic card. So, i couldn't reproduce the errors to file the report. However, I will file a bug report if such problem occurs again. Thanks!